# NSData to primitive

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, macos

I have `NSData *data`. It's value is `000e`.

Hence decimal value is `14`.

Now I want to get this value into primitive `NSUInteger`.

I've tried

```
NSUInteger *hereIWant14 = (NSUInteger *)data.bytes;
```

but `*hereIWant14` value is `3584` what is `e00` in hexa. Now I don't know if there is problem with endians or type size or my thinking is completely wrong and `000e` and `e00` similarity is just pure accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's related to endianness. Use the conversion macros defined in Endian.h:

```
EndianU16_BtoN(value)
EndianU16_NtoB(value)
EndianS32_BtoN(value)
EndianS32_NtoB(value)
EndianU32_BtoN(value)
EndianU32_NtoB(value)
EndianS64_BtoN(value)
EndianS64_NtoB(value)
EndianU64_BtoN(value)
EndianU64_NtoB(value)
etc.
```

Method signatures mean:

*Endian + U for unsigned S for signed + number of bits + **N** is native endianness of the system, **L** is little endian, **B** is big endian*

So if you have an NSData with the content (0x00, 0xE0), and you'd like to interpret it as the value 14, then it contains the data in big endian order, therefore you'll have to use **EndianU32_BtoN** (of course, this macro is the identity transform on big-endian systems and swaps the bytes only on little-endian machines).

Important: to be future-proof, I'd recommend you to use something else instead of NSUInteger, since the width of this type can vary between different systems (e.g. Apple defines NSUInteger as 64 bit on arm64 systems). So, to be explicit about the number of bits, use uint32_t or uint64_t etc.

Edit: Usage for Big-Endian short value

```
NSMutableData * data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:2];
((unsigned char *)data.mutableBytes)[0] = 0x00;
((unsigned char *)data.mutableBytes)[1] = 0x0E;

NSUInteger integer = NSSwapBigShortToHost(*(unsigned short *)data.mutableBytes);

NSLog(@"%d", integer); // prints 14
```

Comment: As Endian.h is legacy from CarbonCore I've used `NSSwapBigIntToHost`. I suppose it does the same thing. After `NSUInteger foo = NSSwapBigIntToHost(*hereIWant14);` foo is `917504` and not `14`.

Comment: It's because BigInt expects 32 bits (4 bytes). You should use NSSwapBigShortToHost for 2 bytes. (edited my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's because of the endianess as said.

If you need down here two pieces of code to read from a NSData:

```
u_int16_t signature;
[data getBytes:&signature           range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
signature = CFSwapInt16(signature);
```

Usually I use CFSwapInt16 or CFSwapInt32 (for u_int32_t). Otherwise if you have to read for example a string:

```
char charArray[length];
[data getBytes:charArray range:NSMakeRange(0, length)];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:charArray length:length];
NSString* string = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
```

Hope it can help!